# Git Error: waitpid for git credential-manager-core get failed: No child processes

Tags: git

Git is giving the error below for every remote command like clone, pull, push. I've tried with Git Bash, CMD, same error on both. But the operation works fine.

The errors:

```
error: waitpid for git credential-manager-core get failed: No child processes
error: waitpid for git credential-manager-core store failed: No child processes
error: waitpid for git credential-manager store failed: No child processes
```

Full log:

```
$ git clone <github-repo>
Cloning into '<github-repo>'...
error: waitpid for git credential-manager-core get failed: No child processes
error: waitpid for git credential-manager-core store failed: No child processes
error: waitpid for git credential-manager store failed: No child processes
remote: Enumerating objects: 2626, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2626/2626), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1950/1950), done.
remote: Total 2626 (delta 899), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (2626/2626), 2.95 MiB | 154.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (899/899), done.
```

My Git version:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.29.2.windows.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and use the latest [git version 2.29.2.windows.*3*](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.29.2.windows.3), which comes with an updated Comes with [Git Credential Manager Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core) v2.0.289.48418.

Make sure to kill any existing Credential Manager process, before trying again with the new Git version.